# Laravel auth0 doesn't "remember" user

Tags: php, laravel, auth0

I have been working with `Laravel` and `Auth0` for some time now and I think I am at the end :)

I am able to log into my application using a link to the `widget` / `hosted page`

Now everything seems to be working and once the page callbacks to my site the user I saved in my database.

However, it doesn't seem that my application remembers the user.

When I attempt to check if a user is logged in:

```
$isLoggedIn = \Auth::check();
```

it says `false`

I have tried debugging multiple functions however with no results so I am lost on where to start with this. Why is this happening?

**My configuration**

So this is my `AuthController`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;


class AuthController extends Controller
{

  public function __construct()
  {

  }

    public function login()
    {
        return \App::make('auth0')->login(null, null, ['scope' => 'openid profile email'], 'code');
    }


    public function logout()
    {
        \Auth::logout();
        return  \Redirect::intended('/');
    }
    

  public function dump()
  {
    $isLoggedIn = \Auth::check();
    return view('dump')
      ->with('isLoggedIn', $isLoggedIn)
      ->with('user',\Auth::user()->getUserInfo())
      ->with('accessToken',\Auth::user()->getAuthPassword());
  }
}
```

Then in my web:

```
Route::get('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@login']);
Route::get('/logout', ['as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'AuthController@logout'])->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/dump', ['as' => 'dump', 'uses' => 'AuthController@dump', 'middleware' => 'auth'])->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/auth0/callback', '\Auth0\Login\Auth0Controller@callback');
```

Comment: which method you are using for user login ?

Comment: @user2486 i am using Auth0 hosted page with a callback to my own application

Comment: @user2486 i have added my configuration to my question